# Call Radgrid UpdateCommand Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am trying to call a `RadGrid_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)` method in a `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I have tried the following but not able to get the correct syntax to call the `UpdateCommand` method.

```
Radgrid_UpdateCommand(sender, e);
```

The error in

Line 1 is `The best overloaded method match for 'RadGrid_UpdateCommand(object, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs)' has some invalid arguments`

Line 2 is `cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs'`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That error is exceptionally self explanatory. Read it back, out loud, and you'll know immediately why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a Rebind() method on the RadGrid that should be used rather than trying to call one of its events.